# Webpack SCSS to CSS extraction not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, webpack

I am trying to extract SCSS to CSS on my `react.js` app using webpack plugin: `extract-text-webpack-plugin`. I am not getting any errors but i can't see any style on my page when i compile. In the following code i am simply trying to change the color of hello world rendered on the screen from black to red. Here are my files:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index.js',
        './sass/styles.scss'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
   module: {
            rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
        },

        { // regular css files
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              loader: 'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
            }),
        },

        { // sass / scss loader for webpack
            test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
        }

    ]
},

plugins: [
     new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
     new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
     new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
   ]
 };
```

**styles.scss**

```
$color : red;

.hello{
   font-color: $color;
   text-align: center;
}
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
     <div>
        <h1 className = "hello">Hello World</h1>
      </div>);
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app';

render ( <App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

What i'm I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're missing `style-loader` from your loader chain.

from the sass-loader [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#examples):

> Chain the sass-loader with the css-loader and the style-loader to immediately apply all styles to the DOM.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
           }, {
               loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
           }, {
               loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. The text is now centered on the screen as specified in the SCSS file but the color isn't changing.

Comment: Got it to work by changing `font-color : $color;` to `color : $color`. Cheers

Comment: This is the correct answer for anyone who doesn't understand, basically the removed the array for the loaders, and added the use option! You sir have my upvote:)

Answer (score 0):

you need import styles.scss in code index.js

`import 'yourlink/styles.scss'`